# In Mac can I remap Control-Delete or Control-W to act as Option-Delete?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping

Option-Delete will remove the word to the left of the cursor.

Is it possible to remap this behavior to Control-Delete or Control-W?

For extra credit... is it feasible to remap CTRL-Left/Right Arrow to do the same thing as Option-Left/Right Arrow, i.e. to jump words?

I'm running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `~/Library/Keybindings/` and save something like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "^\U007F" = deleteWordBackward:; // ctrl-delete (forward delete would be ^\UF728)
    "^\UF702" = moveWordBackward:; // ctrl-left
    "^\UF703" = moveWordForward:; // ctrl-right
}
```

The changes will be applied after you reopen applications. DefaultKeyBinding.dict is not supported by some cross-platform applications, Xcode, or Terminal.

More information: [hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/cocoa-text.html](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/cocoa-text.html)